Issues with android minify after Flutter update 3.22
Since I updated flutter to version 3.22 I keep getting this error when trying to run it.
ERROR:C:\Users\GS\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9233cff7f1f1cb0a6e3f605b6bc688c6\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.0-runtime.jar: R8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyDebugWithR8'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\GS\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9233cff7f1f1cb0a6e3f605b6bc688c6\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.0-runtime.jar:androidx/lifecycle/LiveData$1.class

I have been trying to fix this for 2 days now.
Appreciate your time and help
EDIT: I found out that the issue happens when I use the package flutter_paytabs_bridge: ^2.6.11 (latest at this time)
I'm contacting support right now, if anyone have any information about this issue or why it happens please let me know how to fix it.

Checkout this issue. It was their version that was messing everything up. They released a new version 12 hours ago.
GitHub Issue
Another GitHub Issue

Yes I just used it and it worked great!
